# scala slick handling more than 2 same structure tables by one model

Tags: scala, slick

I'm trying achieve something like log tables.

Let's say I have...

```
final class LogTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[LogModel](tag,"log"){
  def createdAt = column[Timestamp]("created_at")
  //...
}
```

Since log gets too many records for a single table, I want to use multiple tables which has exactly same structure but different names. in another way to say, I want to change only `Table[](tag,"this name")` and If it's possible, I want to let it act like a single table when it gets called from outside.

current my implementation

```
class LogBase(tag: Tag) extends Table[LogModel](tag,"log"){
  def createdAt = column[Timestamp]("created_at")
  //...
}

final class LogTable1(tag:Tag) extends LogBase(tag){
  override val tableName = "log1"
}

final class LogTable2(tag:Tag) extends LogBase(tag){
  override val tableName = "log2"
}

//...
```

writing tables as many as I need is a last option though, is there any way to achieve this in a smart way?

any kind of suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Are these tables separated by date or some other logic?

Comment: yes, It'll be separated by Ids. something like this `idNum % 100` == targetTableNumber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like the way nmat mentioned,
making a table class generator class solve the problem.

```
class LogBase(tableNum: Int){
  class LogTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[LogModel](tag,s"log$tableNum"){
    def createdAt = column[Timestamp]("created_at")
    //...
  }
}
```

and how to use it

```
val tables = (1 to 10).toList.map { num =>
  val clazz = new LogBase(num)
  TableQuery[clazz.LogTable]
}
```

Comment: Interesting, how would you do a foreignKey def on LogTable if the table name in the foreignKey def would also need to be passed as a constructor argument?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply pass the table name as an argument?

```
class LogBase(tag: Tag, id: Int) extends Table[LogModel](tag, s"log${id % 100}")
```

You can create a factory to abstract this logic

Comment: the way you wrote still needs to do something for class name.class name needs to be different as well.
I did try the way you post before asking in here though ended up becoming to require `eval` thing. or Do you have any other solution?